# selecting by label and writing to csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am new to pandas so hoping this is an easy fix. I am trying to create a csv file that only contains the columns called out in df.loc[]. My csv file is currently showing all available rows/columns so the selection is not working.

```
import requests, json
import pandas as pd

# url and date set earlier
response = requests.post(url, date, headers={'Authorization':'OAuth mycode'})

if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    response_json = response.json()
    print('\n\n\nReturned JSON\n\n\n')
    print(json.dumps(response_json, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))

    # df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response_json)
    df = pd.DataFrame(response_json)
    print(df.keys())
    df.loc[:,['Comment','EndTimeLocalized','Id','StartTimeLocalized']]
    df.to_csv("r1.csv")
    print('\nCSV Created\n')
else:
    response.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: Any specific error?

Comment: @PedroLobito no errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is not an in-place operation.

Either assign back to `df` before exporting:

```
df = df.loc[:, ['Comment','EndTimeLocalized','Id','StartTimeLocalized']]
df.to_csv('r1.csv')
```

Or, if you wish to keep `df` unchanged, slice and export immediately afterwards:

```
df.loc[:, ['Comment','EndTimeLocalized','Id','StartTimeLocalized']].to_csv('r1.csv')
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much! I'll accept your answer when it lets me in a few.

Comment: Method-chaining is the currently suggested style to follow in pandas (i.e., the second suggestion).

Comment: @PMende, Method chaining isn't relevant with `to_csv` as `to_csv` returns `None`, not a manipulated dataframe. It depends solely on whether OP wants their slicing to "stick" or not.

Comment: It's relevant to the reassignment of `df` to `df.loc[...]` followed by a second method on the as-returned dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to specify the columns as a keyword-argument in the call to `to_csv`:

```
df.to_csv('r1.csv', columns=['Comment', 'EndTimeLocalized', 'Id', 'StartTimeLocalized'])
```